# $A$, $B$ are compact then there exists $a_0 \in A$ and $b_0 \in B$ such that $d(a_0, b_0) \leq d(a, b)$ for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Assume that $A$, $B$ are compact, disjoint, nonempty subsets of $M$ (metric space). Prove that there are $a_0 \in A$ and $b_0 \in B$ such that for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ we have $d(a_0, b_0) \leq d(a, b)$. (Excercise from Pugh)

My proof:

We have that $A \times B$ is compact (product of compacts). We also have that the distance function is continuous, so it attains it's minimum in the compact set $A \times B$, say $(a_0, b_0)$ so we have $d(a_0, b_0) \leq d(a, b)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it looks like a correct proof.